# Unexpected output printed

Tags: c++, function

I am writing a C++ program that needs to:
declare a struct named `Student` with the following parameters:
- `Student ID`
- `Lastname`
- `Student marks` [for school subject k: 1

I also need to write functions to insert and display each student.

The program however doesn't work.  There are no errors so I think the syntax is correct as it compiles.

Can you guys please help me find the mistake in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    int FN;
    char Lastname[32];
    double marks[10];
};

//y = Number of school subjects;
void decStudent(Student x, int y)
{
    cout << "Insert student ID: ";
    cin >> x.FN;
    cout << "Insert student lastname: ";
    cin >> x.Lastname;
    cout << "Insert student marks: ";
    for ( int i=0; i < y; i++)
    {
        cin >> x.marks[y];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;
}

//v = Number of students;
//t = Number of school subjects;
void BookOut(Student x, int v, int t)
{
    double StudentAvarage = 0;

    cout << x.FN << "        " << x.Lastname << "        ";
    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
    {
        cout << x.marks[j] << "        ";
        StudentAvarage = StudentAvarage + x.marks[j];
    }
    StudentAvarage = StudentAvarage / t;
    cout << StudentAvarage;

}

int main()
{
    int num, k;
    Student book[100];

    cout << "Please insert the number of students: ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "Please insert the amount of school subjects: ";
    cin >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        decStudent(book[i], k);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "   ID   " << "Lastname";

        for (int p = 0; p < k; p++)
        {
            cout << " Mark" << p << " ";
        }

        cout << " Avarage mark ";

        BookOut(book[i], num, k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? *specifically*..

Comment: Displaying the students

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: What about displaying them doesn't work? Again: *specifically*

Comment: It displays me some results, that look like: "-9.421532+061" and some monkey symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has to do with passing parameters correctly and has very little to do with structs.

```
void decStudent(Student x, int y)
```

So when you pass a Student, the function makes a `local copy`.  When the decStudent() function returns, that local copy is destroyed.  This is no different than this:

```
void foo(int x)
{
   x = 10;
}

int main()
{
  int num = 0;
  foo(num);
}
```

The same behavior.  The "num" doesn't change to 10 after the call to foo, since the int is passed by value.

You need to pass by reference, not by value.

```
void decStudent(Student& x, int y)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
decStudent(book[i], k);
```

You are passing a copy of the Student structure and modifying (the copy) inside the function, but the original book[i] won't get modified, you might need to use [pass-by-reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here with as much effort as you have put into debugging yourself, is that you are passing by value void functions in all cases. So none of the changes you make are holding once you exit that function.  This has nothing do with structs.

Answer (score 0):

change your function prototype.
instead of pass by value use pass by reference. as pass by value creates a temporary variable and if you change the value of that temporary variable that change in value will not be reflected in your passed value.

use void decStudent(Student &x, int y)
instead of void decStudent(Student x, int y)